# ggplot heatmap failing to fill tiles

Tags: r, ggplot2, heatmap

This (minimal, self-contained) example is broken:

```
require(ggplot2) 

min_input = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4)
input_range = c(4, 470, 1003, 4, 470, 1003, 4, 470, 1003)
density = c(
    1.875000e-01,
    5.598958e-04,
    0.000000e+00,
    1.250000e-02,
    3.841146e-04,
    0.000000e+00,
    1.250000e-02,
    1.855469e-04,
    0.000000e+00)       

df = data.frame(min_input, input_range, density)

pdf(file='problemspace.pdf')
ggplot(df, aes(x=min_input, y=input_range, fill=density)) +
    geom_tile()
dev.off()
```

Producing:

[image: gapped tiles]

Why are there big gaps?

Comment: Maybe x&y are not factors? Try `ggplot(densities, aes(x=factor(min_input), y=factor(input_range), fill=density)) +
    geom_tile()`

Comment: @ddiez That replaces one problem with another. There are no gaps but the scaling is lost. Conceptually, these should be continuous variables and not factors.

Comment: I see. You want unequal tile sizes like in the examples at the bottom of the help page for [geom_tile](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/geom_tile.html), right?

Comment: @ddiez Unequal tile sizes, sure - or interpolated little tiles. But I'm not sure that the approach at the bottom of geom_tile will work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are gaps because you don't have data for all of the tiles. If you want to try to fill them in, your only option is to interpolate (assuming you don't have access to additional data). In theory, `geom_raster()` (a close relative of `geom_tile()`) supports interpolation. However, according to [this github issue](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/issues/794), that feature is not currently functional.

As a workaround, however, you can use qplot, which is just a wrapper around ggplot:

```
qplot(min_input, input_range, data=df, geom="raster", fill=density, interpolate=TRUE)
```

If there is too much space between the points that you have data for, you will still end up with blank spaces in your graph, but this will extend the range that you can estimate values for.

EDIT:

Based on the example that you posted, this will be the output

[image]

As you can see, there is a vertical band of white running through the middle, due to the lack of data points between 2 and 4.

Comment: How do I quantify "too much space"?

Comment: Based on the example, it looks like anything that doesn't have a data point within .5 x units is too far. This is a byproduct of the exact interpolation algorithm used, which I do not know off the top of my head.

Comment: Yeah, okay, upon further investigation, geom_raster() specifically breaks the area up into evenly sized tiles. Tiles are colored based on data points that fall within them, and the color between tiles is linearly interpolated (so a distance-weighted color average is taken). Tiles with no data are white.

Comment: OK. So I have to do interpolation myself?

Comment: If you want it to go across larger distances, then the answer would seem to be yes, since there's no way to specify an alternative interpolation function.